# Trouble using the 'date' function inside a 'create' statement or 'exercise' statement

Tags: daml

Here is a code snippet:

```
car1AddCid <- submit dealer1 do
    carCid <- create Car with
      dealer = dealer1
      insurer = insurance1
      vin = "1A"
      daily_insurance_rate = 1.5 
      daily_rate_APD = 0.16
      covered = False 
      observers = [insurance1]
      date_vehicle_added = date 1970 Jan 1   -- must be initialized to something
    exercise carCid Add_Car with startCoverage = date 2019 Apr 5
```

The use of the date function is not acceptable. I tried putting the `yyyy mmm d` in `""` and in `()`.  How are dates specified?

Answer (score 2):

The way you are specifying the dates looks right.

Since you posted a more complete code snippet in [Syntax errors in Main.daml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753020/syntax-errors-in-main-daml), I'm able to hazard a guess and say that you are missing the `DA.Date` standard library. Try adding the line `import DA.Date` to the beginning of your file:

```
daml 1.2
module Main where

import DA.Date
```